# R: assign dataframe column values using external vectors

Tags: r, dataframe, if-statement, vector, variable-assignment

I have a dataframe that looks like this:

```
df <- data.frame(sample = c(1,2,3,4), code = c("D", "B", "A", "B"))
```

I also have two vectors that look like this:

```
code <- c("A", "B", "C")
name <- c("Apple", "Bat", "Cat")
```

I know if I wanted to use the vectors to assign a "name" based on a matching "code" in the dataframe, I could do something like the following:

```
# This returns the correct output
df$name <- NA
df$name <- ifelse(df$code == code[1], name[1],
                       ifelse(df$code == code[2], name[2],
                              ifelse(df$code == code[3], name[3], NA)))
```

However, I don't want to have to write a new ifelse line for each new entry in the list as it and the dataframe grow/change over time. Is it possible to loop over each code/name pair to assign a value in the dataframe column a bit more dynamically?

Something like this (though this doesn't work):

```
df$name <- NA
for(i in 1:length(code)) {
  for(j in 1:length(name)) {
  df$name <- ifelse(df$code == code[i], name[j], NA)
  }
}
```

I've also been looking at Map (also doesn't work):

```
df$name <- NA
assign_name <- function(code, name, df) {
  df$name <- Map(function(code, name) {
    ifelse(df$code == code, name, NA)
  }, code, name)
  return(df)
}
assign_name(code, name, df)
# Error in `$<-.data.frame`(`*tmp*`, name, value = list(A = c(NA, NA, "Apple", :
# replacement has 3 rows, data has 4
```

I'm struggling to Google this one, feels like I'm missing something simple. Thank you in advance to all the humans out there who are smarter than me.

Comment: Your expected result is missing. However, I suspect this is what you are after: `df = data.frame(sample = c(1,2,3,4), code = c("D", "B", "A", "B")); lookup = data.frame(code = c("A", "B", "C"), name = c("Apple", "Bat", "Cat")); df$name = lookup$name[match(df$code, lookup$code)]`. If so, study the help file of `match()`, e.g. execute `help("match")`.

Comment: Boom. Just like that. Turning my vectors into a dataframe to use match seems like the way to go.  Thank you! If you want to write an answer out below I'll accept it.

Comment: That's kind, thank you. Due to potential duplicates I have the feeling a comment is more appropriate. There are numerous questions of similar content out there. All answered with `match`, `setNames`, and friends. Notice that, there is no need to create a `lookup` data frame, two separate vectors are fine also.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
lut <- setNames(name, code)
df$name <- lut[df$code]
```

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively please try

```r
df <- data.frame(sample = c(1,2,3,4), code = c("D", "B", "A", "B"))

df2 <- data.frame(code = c("A", "B", "C"), name = c("Apple", "Bat", "Cat"))

df %>% left_join(df2, join_by(code))
```

<sup>Created on 2024-03-01 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

```r
  sample code  name
1      1    D  <NA>
2      2    B   Bat
3      3    A Apple
4      4    B   Bat
```